# How can I create Business Models on different schemas using Database Actions on Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I have created a few Business Models using Database Actions but if I'm signed in as admin I can only create models on objects in the admin schema.
How would I create a Business Model against, say, SH schema?

Answer (score 0):

Business Models are always created in the current schema.  Log into SQL Developer Web / Database Actions as the user you want the business model to be created in. You can find more information about creating Business Models here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/creating-business-models.html#GUID-0FA57151-9464-407F-866C-75F0F23B0DC3

Business models are deployed in the database as analytic views, attribute dimensions and hierarchy views.  You can also create analytic view objects using SQL Developer (desktop) in any schema for which you have the necessary privileges.